# Session in nodejs is being partially stored

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am developing an application which store a **cassie** object in session. Here **cassie object is being partially stored** in the session.

Here is screenshot to **set session** named as cassie

[image]

Here is screenshot to **get session** named as cassie

[image]

Here only consistencies and types object is being fetched while not other.
What am i doing wrong? and what should do to store cassie object in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your session object is serializing by call JSON.stringify() and storing in session as a plain text in json format. Functions can't be stored in JSON format and skipped. Here some sample:

```
var session = {
    not_stored_as_text: function() {
        console.log('test');
    },
    stored_as_text_ok: [ "Some string", {}, 1 ]
};

console.log(session); // { not_stored_as_text: [Function], stored_as_text_ok: [ 'Some string', {}, 1 ] }
console.log(JSON.stringify(session)); // {"stored_as_text_ok":["Some string",{},1]}
```

for solve that problem, you can store in session plain data needed for auth, and create  your cassie object from them manualy.